# Hide an element's next sibling with Javascript

Tags: javascript, element, hide, siblings

I have an element grabbed from `document.getElementById('the_id')`. How can I get its next sibling and hide it? I tried this but it didn't work:

```
elem.nextSibling.style.display = 'none';
```

Firebug error was `elem.nextSibling.style is undefined`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

it's because Firefox considers the whitespace between element nodes to be text nodes (whereas IE does not) and therefore using `.nextSibling` on an element gets that text node in Firefox.

It's useful to have a function to use to get the next element node. Something like this

```
/* 
   Credit to John Resig for this function 
   taken from Pro JavaScript techniques 
*/
function next(elem) {
    do {
        elem = elem.nextSibling;
    } while (elem && elem.nodeType !== 1);
    return elem;        
}
```

then you can do

```
var elem = document.getElementById('the_id');
var nextElem = next(elem); 

if (nextElem) 
    nextElem.style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: But `elem` still might be null.

Comment: No it doesn’t. It just guaratees that `nextSibling` is not accessed when `elem` is “not true” or `elem.nodeType == 1`. But if there isn’t such an element, `elem` is just the last sibling node regardless of what type it is.

Comment: Here’s an example: var elem = document.createElement("div");
elem.appendChild(document.createTextNode("foo"));
elem.appendChild(document.createTextNode("bar"));
alert(next(elem.firstChild) === null); // "true"

Comment: just wanted to confirm this is the another answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15322350/4119808 but not in focus. Is anything wrong with it?

Answer (score 14):

Take a look at the [Element Traversal API](http://www.w3.org/TR/ElementTraversal/#interface-elementTraversal%29:), that API moves between Element nodes only. This Allows the following:

```
elem.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'none';
```

And thus avoids the problem inherent in nextSibling of potentially getting non-Element nodes (e.g. TextNode holding whitespace)

Comment: i think this is the best and easiest way i dont understand why people didn't focused..

Comment: Works out if the box. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> Firebug error was elem.nextSibling.style is undefined.

because nextSibling can be a text-node or other node type

```
do {
   elem = elem.nextSibling;
} while(element && elem.nodeType !== 1); // 1 == Node.ELEMENT_NODE
if(elem) elem.style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: +1 For checking if `elem` is not null before accessing the `style` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try looping through the children of this element using something like:

```
var i=0;
(foreach child in elem)
{
   if (i==0)
   {
     document.getElementByID(child.id).style.display='none';
    }
}
```

Please make appropriate corrections to the syntax.