# Dynamically created elements from codebehind need to be inserted between specific elements

Tags: html, vb.net, insert, dynamically-generated

I created a method and pass the element type, id, and any inner text that instantiates a new html element. The last statement: `Me.Controls.Add(element)` adds it to the end of the page, but I would like it to be inserted in a specific position (between 2 divs within a form). What I am describing is very similar to this post on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254033/javascript-inserting-elements-dynamically-in-a-specific-position), although it was for javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps look at using a PlaceHolder control..