# Javascript function locating right element

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html

This is partial markup:

```
 <tr class="Comment">        
    <td  class="CommentCheck">
       <input id="ctl00_col2_rptComments_ctl01_chkBox" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$col2$rptComments$ctl01$chkBox" /> 
       <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$col2$rptComments$ctl01$hdnFldItemID" id="ctl00_col2_rptComments_ctl01_hdnFldItemID" value="35" />
    </td>

    <td class="CommentBy" >
        <span id="ctl00_col2_rptComments_ctl01_lblUserName" title="Posted by name">Jack</span>                         

    <tr>
        <td colspan="100%" class="BodyComment">
            <div id="ctl00_col2_rptComments_ctl01_TheTable" style="padding: 0 0 0 40px;display:none;">                   

                <span id="ctl00_col2_rptComments_ctl01_TextBox1" style="display:inline-block;width:75%; border: thin solid #000000;padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;">I know it all now!</span>

            </div>                                         

        </td>
    </tr>           
 </tr>
```

On the page there are many rows like that, I want to find all rows where chkBox is marked, and unhide/hide the div with cleintId='TheTable'..

This is part of my javascript function:

```
  function SelectClick() {

            var TargetBaseControl = document.getElementById("commentsTable");                        
            var Inputs = TargetBaseControl.getElementsByTagName('input');

            for (var n = 0; n < Inputs.length; ++n)
                if (Inputs[n].type == 'checkbox' && Inputs[n].id.indexOf('chkBox', 0) >= 0)

 {
```

How to locate the div with clientId 'TheTable'?

Comment: It looks like the end of the question is missing.

Comment: Did you paste all your code there, or is something missing?

Comment: If you are asking about javascript function then  yes, this what i wrote so far, now i need to locate the div 'TheTable'

Comment: I'd add that making a div with an id of "TheTable" is a bit misleading.  A div is not a table :)

Comment: You aren't closing the second TD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it relates to your question, but if you need the ID of the div to hide you can do something like this:

```
<asp:Panel ID="TheTable" runat="server">...</asp:Panel>

<script...>
... var div = document.getElementById('<%= TheTable.ClientID %>')
</script>
```

Then you can hide/show it with something like this:

```
div.style.display = 'none'; // hide
div.style.display = 'block'; // show
```

The selection of the checkboxes seems right from the code I'm seeing.

**Edit**: OK, the first solution is not good. Maybe after obtaining the checkbox control chkCtrl (=Inputs[n]) you can do this:

```
var trCtrl = chkCtrl.parentNode.parentNode; // Should be the parent TR
var divCtrl = trCtrl.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]; // I assume it will always find a div there and that your table is the only div.
```

Note that this is untested code, so I'm not 100% sure it will work. But this is the general idea. jQuery does *basically* the same thing, but wraps it nicely for (much needed) convenience.

Also I see there are two embedded TRs in your example. This is not correct and I assumed there would be a single TR that contains all that HMTL markup.

**Edit 2**: If you need the TRs to come one after the other then the proposed idea  won't work directly since the div won't be inside the children of the first TR. What you can do is to obtain the parent TR of the checkbox and obtain the next sibling (you can find a method for that here: [Hide an element's next sibling with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868407/hide-an-elements-next-sibling-with-javascript)). After you find the sibling you can search inside for the div.

Another method could be used if you don't need the table div to be an ASP control (i.e. if you can put directly a div instead of the asp:Panel that you use). In this case you could control the IDs (I assume you use a repeater to put the items there):

```
<div id="theTable<%# Container.ItemIndex %>"...>...</div>
```

The same value could be used in the checkbox:

```
Value="<%# Container.ItemIndex %>"...
```

and you could use that value from the checkbox to get the div directly (something like this):

```
var div = document.getElementById('theTable' + chkCtrl.value)
```

Comment: the document.getElementById('<%= TheTable.ClientID %>') will give me the div that is related to the current checkbox?
there are amny checknoxes and many "TheTable" divs

Comment: no :(, i misunderstood and thought there will be a single 'TheTable' div. In this case I would go with Brandon's solution.

Comment: about the second tr, yes it's misplaced it should come after the first tr and not inside.

Comment: but if i put the second tr under first tr i lose a parent!

Answer (score 1):

You could easily use jQuery to do this. I would put a unique class on your checkboxes and divs, like "myCheck" and "myDiv" or something.

```
$(".myCheck").each(function () {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(this).parent("tr").find(".myDiv").show();
  } else {
    $(this).parent("tr").find(".myDiv").hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: Well I don't know jQuery, can I do this parent-child linkage with javascript?

Comment: This _is_ javascript - it's library that you can load and gives you access to all kinds of goodies.

Comment: Yes, you can walk over the DOM tree in pure javascript using parentNode and childNodes properties of the nodes (http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/dombasics)