# nextSibling ul li ul

Tags: javascript, nextsibling

i'm not sure but if i understood right js nextSibling focus next node ? So why i get trouble, when i want to select ul in a li ?

```
    <ul>
<li><input id="btn-page" type=button onclick="displayMenu();" /></li>
    <ul class="hide">
        <li>Some text</li>
    </ul>
    <li>...</li>
   </ul>
```

And my js function :

```
    function displayMenu() {
   var idMenu = event.target.id;
   var ulDisplay = document.getElementById(idMenu).nextSibling;
   ulDisplay.style.display = 'block';
}
```

I think i forgot something but i don't know why. Thanks for help :)

Comment: The edited html isn't valid. There are only `<li />`s allowed as direct childs of an `<ul>` - http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @andreas pointed out the structure of your HTML is not valid because you can't have a UL as child of a UL. But you can have a UL as a child of LI. So consider updating your HTML in this way. Helper function "Next()" from previous similar answer [Hide an element's next sibling with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868407/hide-an-elements-next-sibling-with-javascript) used to find the UL

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .hide { display: none; }
        </style>
        <title>Title</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function next(elem) {
                do {
                    elem = elem.nextSibling;
                } while (elem && elem.nodeType != 1);
                return elem;                
            }

            function displayMenu(id) {
                var ulDisplay = next(document.getElementById(id));
                ulDisplay.style.display = 'block';
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input id="btn-page" value="show" type=button onclick="displayMenu(this.id);" />
                <ul class="hide"><li>Some text</li></ul>
            </li>
            <li>...</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for answering but it didn't work. And i don't understand why using parentNode.nextSibling. When doing it, id focus himself (parentNode go back in node, nextSibling focus next node so its cancelled each, no ?)

Comment: Your comment relates before my latest edit, try it instead. No parentNode from the INPUT takes you to the LI that is wrapping it. Then the nextSibling is the UL assuming there is no whitespace between </li> and the <ul>

Comment: Okay don't see about whitespace, sorry. I had 4 tabulations so it's why it didn't work. I forgot indentation and it's good.
Thanks for helping :)

Comment: No problem. The whitespace caught me out too when I was testing. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

This way seems better.

HTML

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <input id="btn1" type='button' onclick="displayMenu(event);" />
 </li>
 <li><ul id="page1" style="display: none" class="hide">
  <li>Some text</li>
 </ul></li>
 <li>...</li>
</ul> <
```

JS

```
function displayMenu(event) {
    var id = event.target.id.substring(3);
    var ulDisplay = document.getElementById("page" + id);
    ulDisplay.style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: I am quite sure the OP is trying to perform the toggle action and it's not working. I can't see how your answer solves this.

Comment: I was showing another way to get the siblings. Where I think the OP problem was.

Comment: No sorry, i success to focus input's id, then i want to get a way to focus following ul (which is next node after my input, isn't it ?)

Comment: @TikTaZ by sending the page you want to show in the function might simplify it a bit.

Comment: yeah but i have 4 input button with a following ul list, so i want to keep my way and make one generic function for all 4 button.

Comment: Problem resolved, shit was about whitespace.
Thanks to your time wasted to helping me :)